# Is there a simple way to get li:gt(-1) in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to get `li:gt(-1)` in jQuery? Or greater than or equal to zero using jQuery's `:gt` filter?

When the I use the following code, it is not taking `li:gt(-1)`:

```
 $('#Input li:gt(-1)').each(function()
```

Comment: Isn't index "greater than or equal to zero" just all of them? In which case you don't need `:gt` at all.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `:gt(-l)`? Is `l` negative to begin with? Are you looking for `:lt()`?

Comment: correct, li:gt(-1), that is a negative (One) -l

Comment: @Bruc, understood, but please note that `l` (lowercase `L`) is not the same thing as `1`, and we're not using typewriters anymore. In your case, `slice()` is probably the way to go, see @pimvdb's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to start at 0 instead of -1, and do a "greater-than-or-equal-to" selector:

```
$('.someClass:eq('+i+'), .someClass:gt('+i+')')
```

Or, with a little less duplication:

```
$('.someClass').filter(':eq('+i+'), :gt('+i+')')
```

Comment: thanks Elliot for understanding my question, its working great

Comment: thanks worked like a charm: :gt(-1) -> :eq(0),:gt(0)

Answer (score 4):

What about [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)? Passing one index means anything from that index and up, so add `1` to get `gt` rather than `gte`.

```
 $('#Input li').slice(1 - l)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all elements at index "greater than or equal to zero" then you just want all the elements, and you don't need the `:gt` pseudo-selector:

```
$('#Input li').each(function() {
    //Do whatever
});
```

**Update** (based on comments)

I'm still not exactly sure what you're aiming for, but if you want to know the index of the element referred to by the current iteration, you can use the first argument of [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('#Input li').each(function(index, elem) {
    //index is the index of the current element
});
```

Comment: $('#input li:gt') will be use as a counter starting at zero and will add to it

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're after, but see my edit.

Comment: I want the selector to start at a certain index if I put $('#input li:gt(0)') it will start at 1 and li:gt(-l) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think you just need:

`$('#Input li').each(function()`

It will return a jQuery object that is indexed from 0.

Therefore every match will be 0 or greater.